# String from method to String in class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, inheritance, immutability

Probably I am doing something very stupid.

But, I have a class `Zaalactivity` with the `String naam`.

```
public class ZaalActivity extends MainActivity {
public String naam;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaal);

ListViewItemClick();

}
```

Now, when I try to inherit `naam` in my child class, it still has a value of `null`, how is it possible to inherit the data from `naam` in the method `displayToastForID(long id)`?

```
public void ListViewItemClick() {

   final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListviewCollection);
   myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long idInDB) {
         displayToastForID(idInDB);
         openWerkenInColActivity();
         //Toast.makeText(ZaalActivity.this, naam, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
   });
}

public void openWerkenInColActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ZaalActivity.this, WerkenInColActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void displayToastForID(long id) {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getRowCollection(id);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        long IdDB = cursor.getLong(Integer.parseInt(DBAdapter.COL_COLLECTION_ID));
        naam = (cursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(DBAdapter.COL_COLLECTION_NAME)));

        Toast.makeText(ZaalActivity.this, naam, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to do `naam = "lala";` not `String naam = "lala";`

Comment: It doesn't really seem to change anything.

Comment: Post the code where you are actually calling `ChangeNaam`.  I don't see the call anywhere in this.

Comment: I didn't want to add all my code so I just invented a name. But, the string naam is in yhe displayToastForID(long id) method.

Answer (score 0):

You're being bitten by what is known as variable shadowing. You're also using `=` when you probably mean `==`.

You need to do:

```
public void ChangeNaam() {
    if(blabla == blabal) {
        naam = "lala";
    }
}
```

Your code as is declares a local variable called `naam` unrelated to the field `naam`, shadowing it, and so you're only changing the local variable, but of course, that local variable will go out of scope and get garbage collected after the function returns, so you see no difference, because you didn't change the `naam` you intended to.

Comment: So, I changed it. But nothing different happens. I will add the whole method. 'code public void displayToastForID(long id){
            Cursor cursor = myDB.getRowCollection(id);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                long IdDB = cursor.getLong(Integer.parseInt(DBAdapter.COL_COLLECTION_ID));
                naam = (cursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(DBAdapter.COL_COLLECTION_NAME)));

                Toast.makeText(ZaalActivity.this, naam, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();







            }
            cursor.close();


        }'

Comment: I added it to the original question

Answer (score 0):

change it to this .

```
public void ChangeNaam(){
  if(blabla==blabla){
   naam = "lala"
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.